# High-low by hour in xts r

Tags: r, xts

I have my stock ticker data by the minute in xts format. I use `to.hourly` to get to hourly.

Now I want to calculate High-Low from the hourly xts but I don't know how.

I tried to convert using `as.data.table` but the date column disappears.

```
NQ = as.xts(NQ)
NQ_Hourly = to.hourly(NQ)
NQ_h_t = as.data.table(NQ_hourly, keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is unless you post some of your data. If I call `as.data.table(df, keep.rownames=T)` on an `xts` object I get returned a data table with an index column that contains the date.

Comment: Ah, yes my bad.  Thanks Gabriel and sorry for the lousy post.